# Accessing logged in username in Github wiki / Markdown

Tags: github, gitlab, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to create a wiki page for my official project and I would like to display the logged in user's name in my wiki page or README file. Iw this possible in GitHub / GitLab? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible with GitHub or GitLab Markdown, though in both cases a logged in user will see their avatar as part of the main site navigation.

Markdown is a [markup language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language). It doesn't support variables or dynamic content.